# Grouped bar plot in ggplot with y values based on combination of 2 categorical variables?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a grouped bar plot in ggplot, in which there should be 4 bars per each x value. Here is a subset of my data (actual data is about 4x longer):

```
Verb_Type,Frame,proportion_type,speaker
mental,V CP,0.209513024,Child
mental,V NP,0.138731597,Child
perception,V CP,0.017167382,Child
perception,V NP,0.387528402,Child
mental,V CP,0.437998087,Parent
mental,V NP,0.144086707,Parent
perception,V CP,0.042695836,Parent
perception,V NP,0.398376853,Parent
```

What I want is to plot Frame as the x values and proportion_type as the y values, but with the bars based on both Verb_Type and speaker. So for each x value (Frame), there would be 4 bars grouped together - a bar each for the proportion_type value corresponding to mental~child, mental~parent, perception~child, perception~parent. I need for the fill color to be based on Verb_Type, and the fill "texture" (saturation or something) based on speaker. I do *not* want stacked bars, as it would not accurately represent the data.

I don't want to use facet grids because I find it visually difficult to compare all 4 bars when they're separated into 2 groups. I want to group all the bars together so that the visualization is easier. But I can't figure out how to make the appropriate groupings. Is this something I can do in ggplot, or do I need to manipulate the data before plotting? I tried using melt to reshape the data, but either I was doing it wrong, or that's not what I actually should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `interaction()` (i.e. get all unique pairings) between `df$Verb_Type` and `df$speaker` to get the column groupings you are after. You can pass this directly to `ggplot` or make a new variable ahead of time:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Frame, y = proportion_type,
               group = interaction(Verb_Type, speaker), fill = Verb_Type, alpha = speaker)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(.5, 1))
```

Or:

```
df$grouper <- interaction(df$Verb_Type, df$speaker)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Frame, y = proportion_type,
               group = grouper, fill = Verb_Type, alpha = speaker)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(.5, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! The group = interaction() was what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Also, @Nathan Day, a follow-up question: I assume it is possible to re-order the bars in the groupings? so that each pair of Verb_Type bars are next to each other?

Comment: Nevermind - to do that I only need to change the order of the variables in interaction().

Comment: glad it got you unstuck, I always like building these sorts of things outside of the `ggplot()` so I can control the plotting order by using specified factor levels

Comment: also if the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it, so we can keep our open/unanswered question percentage low on SO-R